# Updated data don't seem in DRF api response

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, django-celery

The updated data doesn't seem in api response. When I add or update some data in admin panel it doesn't affect to api response. To fix it i must write docker-compose restart. How can i fix this problem

I supposed that this problem comes from caches issue. Therefore i add cache configuration in settings like this:

```
`CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }`
```

But it doesn't fix problem